# Is it possible to map a domain name url to an Azure storage endpoint with Azure DNS service?

Tags: azure

I would like to be able to map a domain url www.domain.com/* to account.blob.core.windows.net/www.domain.com/*

Is there a way to do this with Azure services like Azure DNS or some URL rewrite service? I would like to avoid running my own reverse proxy if possible.

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking to do (`yourstorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/www.domain.com`) is impossible. You cannot have dots in the container name (naming rules are [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd135715.aspx)).

What you *can* do is map your domain name to your storage name, so that:

`www.mysitename.com/container/blob.extension`

maps to

`yourstorageaccountname.blob.core.windows.net/container/blob.extension`

Details for mapping custom domain names are [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-custom-domain-name/).

**EDIT** - Per your question via comment, regarding mapping the domain name to a container path: It doesn't work that way. A given custom domain name (more specifically, a custom domain name with subdomain, such as `www`) maps to a blob endpoint; there's no way to map it to a specific container. To accomplish separation of content in the way you're asking, you'd need to embed the domain name in the blob URI's (as the container name). Alternatively, you could separate your content by creating separate storage accounts, one per domain name (though this doesn't create domain-specific containers, as you're trying to do).

Comment: can I map `yourstorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/www-domain-com`
the point is if I have multiple domains, can I simply map them to different containers in a transparent way?

I want `www.domain1.com` to map to `account.blob.core.windows.net/www-domain1-com/index.html`
`www.domain2.com` to map to `account.blob.core.windows.net/www-domain2-com/index.html`

and so on

Comment: No, it doesn't work that way. It maps to the blob storage endpoint, as I stated.